why do we still need to write contracts in Rust?
I have a question that has troubled me for a long time. Since Solana contract instructions can be called using TypeScript and there are SDKs available for them (such as spl-token, Metaplex core and bubblegum...), why do we still need to write contracts in Rust? Wouldn't it be more convenient to just use TypeScript to call instructions and write the logic?
Since I can use TypeScript to implement the logic of the contract, I think It might not need to develop a Solana program ?. Ultimately, the Solana program we write is just an instruction provided for the frontend to call.
Looking forward to your response.

There is actually a project for writing solana programs in typescript called
poseidon.
https://github.com/Turbin3/poseidon
Many things on Solana you dont need to write your own program actually. Many protocols have js apis that you can use the interact with them.

Thx for your response! So, if it’s a small project, using TS would be fine, and for a larger project, Rust would be better. Is that correct?

I would recommend rust and probably the anchor frame work for now. Poseidon is still quite new. But give it a try :)

To add some more information to Jonas's answer, the Solana virtual machine only executes a special form of BPF bytecode. This bytecode can be emitted from any language.
Currently, however, there's only an LLVM backend maintained by the Anza team: https://github.com/anza-xyz/llvm-project/
This means that we can only write Solana programs in languages with an LLVM frontend. The main supported languages for that are Rust and C. However, it's also possible to port any compiler with an LLVM frontend to emit Solana BPF bytecode. For example, here's a Zig compiler that uses the Solana LLVM backend (shameless self-promotion, I'm maintaining it right now) https://github.com/joncinque/solana-zig-bootstrap
We could eventually support Typescript, but we need a way to eventually emit BPF bytecode. It looks like Poseidon's idea is to transpile from Typescript to Rust, and then compile Rust to BPF.
